# Scene delegate class couldn't be loaded even though "Delegate Class Name" is provided in plist

Tags: swift, ipados, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to write an iPadOS/macOS Catalyst app that supports multiple windows. When I run, I get the log error message:

```
[SceneConfiguration] Info.plist configuration "Default Configuration" for UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication contained UISceneDelegateClassName key, but could not load class with name "WTF? Viewer.SceneDelegate".
```

The "Delegate Class Name" entry in the Info.plist file is filled in and has the value (without the quotes) "WTF? Viewer.SceneDelegate". The class exists. Why isn't it able to load it?

I've tried several variations of the "Delegate Class Name" value such as:

```
WTF?\ Viewer.SceneDelegate
WTF\?\ Viewer.SceneDelegate
WTF?\\ Viewer.SceneDelegate
WTF\\?\\ Viewer.SceneDelegate
```

Answer (score 5):

For the value of "Delegate Class Name" in Info.plist, use:

```
$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate
```

Comment: Note that this is only needed for a Swift project. If it's an Objective-C project, you just need the `SceneDelegate` part.

Comment: Thanks. I added the Swift tag to the question.

Comment: What if I don't have the SceneDelegate in the app target? Xcode creates the SceneDelegate, by default in the app target. In my case, I moved it to a different target (a static lib). But now, how do I set the SceneDelegate here? $(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME) doesn't work in this case (as the SceneDelegate is not in the app target.
I tried Target.ClassName, but that didn't work.

Comment: Have created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74444077/set-scenedelegate-in-info-plist-file) for the issue commented above.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. The correct prefix is $(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME) as the systems needs to know the Swift module (if you are creating the delegate using the Swift language) to load the class from.

For many projects $(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME) is the same as $(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME).

Look in your project compiler settings for the entry "Swift Module Name", that is the name to use.

Comment: `Look in your project compiler settings for the entry "Swift Module Name", that is the name to use.` - Can you elaborate? I'm unable to find this.